# Make sure you have somewhere to go / somewhere to work / something lined up etc

Tags: idiomatic-language

Please consider someone who is working in a company and is not satisfied with his working conditions and decides to open his heart to one of his co-workers. The colleague notices that he is thinking about resigning; therefore he is going to sympathize with him and wants to give his advice and say "First, find another job and then quit working there." Does the self-made sentences below sound natural to you:

> - First, make sure you have somewhere to **go** then quit working there.
> - First, make sure you have somewhere to **work** then quit working there.
> - First, make sure you have something **lined up** then quit working there.

**Note:** In my mother language, we have a simile. In such conditions we refer to a hiking or mountaineering in rocky places / mountains when a mountaineer wants to go up the rocks, first they must make sure that they have stepped on a solid and confident peace of stone and then step forward; otherwise, they may fall down the rocks. So, this is the expression we use in these situations and say:

> - You have to make sure that you've put your foot on a confident place on a rock and then step forward

Meaning:

> - You have to find a job and then quit working there.

This is the fixed expression which I am looking for its equivalent in especially AE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third sentence comes closest to native

> Make sure you have something *lined up* first, before quitting / leaving.

Obviously, from he context this sentence is about work and the current location, so somethings can be implied.

Saying "somewhere to go" may mean "some place to live / stay".
Saying "some place to work" may mean "a location to work" e.g. office suite.